# Can one use a calculator for the EASA part 66 exam?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, easa-regulations, easa

For the first 3 modules you will need to do some calculations, is a calculator allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Calculators are not allowed during examination. Therefore all calculations should be feasible without a calculator. Where a question involves calculations not feasible without a calculator, such as root 10, then the question should specify the approximate value of root 10

I found the answer on page 7 of [this pdf](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/QDB%20Methodology.pdf).

Comment: Can you post the link to that “some site”? Definitely someone will benefit from it